# Modifying the Windows task bar width and location

Tags: windows, taskbar

I use a setup with 3 monitors using eyefinity, this creates a 5760x1080 resolution. When this resolution is set the task bar spreads across all 3 monitors with the start button on the far left monitor and the tray and time on the far right. This is a major PIA!

I want to have a little app that:

1. it allows me to change the width of the taskbar (eg. to 1920 wide)
2. send it to any monitor I'd like

This would allow me to have a task bar that resembled the normal 1920x1080 task bar that is only on one monitor.

I don't care what language as long as it does not involve a third party application or a non standard language (aka proprity language)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. If you are tricking Windows into thinking you have only a single monitor then you have to accept the consequences.

You might dock the taskbar vertically. I'd be inclined to go back to 3 monitors.